# Display and sort numeric column as ordered categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a column of my table that is a float with value between 0-1. I would like it to display as an ordered label but sort by the original value.

For example with the following rule set...

```
if (value > 0.55) {
    "high"
} else if (value > 0.45) {
    "moderate"
} else {
   "low"
}
```

and the values...

```
[0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9]
```

I would like the column to read...

```
|moderate|
|high    |
|low     |
|low     |
|high    |
```

But still be sortable by the original values.

I tried writing an extension with `jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort` without much luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: filter your data using your rule set, each filtering will return an "array" of data with each type and then you display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to generate content for cell only when that content is displayed. jQuery DataTables will use original numerical value for ordering.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 1,
            render: function(data, type, full, meta){
                if(type === 'display'){
                    if (data > 0.55) {
                        data = "high ";
                    } else if (data > 0.45) {
                        data = "moderate";
                    } else {
                        data = "low";
                    }                    
                }

                return data;
            }
        }
   ]    
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/5s07onyv/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly do not know how datatables work, but below snippet might give you idea.

```js
label = (n => (n > 0.45 ? (n > 0.55 ? 'high' : 'moderate') : 'low'))
ary = [ 0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9 ]
ary.forEach(i => console.log(label(i)))
```

below snippet is a humble attempt to render those data as table items.

```js
label = (n => (n > 0.45 ? (n > 0.55 ? 'high' : 'moderate') : 'low'))

as_row_item = (el) => "<tr><td>"+el+"</td><td>";

ary = [ 0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9 ]
ary.forEach(i => document.querySelector("table").innerHTML += as_row_item(label(i)));
```

```css
table, tr, td {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: `label = (n => (n > 0.45 ? (n > 0.55 ? 'high' : 'moderate') : 'low'))` I get the *idea* that ES6 let you produce oneliners with even higher level of obscurity :)